# Use of ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

I have written the following code to create a list. after that I put the view in a ScrollView.

```
struct ListView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedState = SortState.commonName
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    let alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: nil, content: {
                Picker("Selected Sort State", selection: $selectedState) {
                    ForEach(SortState.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { sortState in
                        Text(sortState.rawValue).tag(sortState)
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).padding(.horizontal)
                
                                
                SearchBarView(searchText: $searchText)
                
                ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                    itemList.overlay(SectionIndexTitles(proxy: proxy, titles: alphabet))
                }
                            
            })
            .navigationTitle("Items")
        }
    }
    
    var itemList: some View {
        return List{
                ForEach(alphabet, id:\.self) { letter in
                        Section(header: Text(letter).id(letter)) {
                            ForEach(items.filter(
                                {
                                    (item) -> Bool in
                                    item.name.prefix(1) == letter
                                }
                            ), id:\.itemId) { item in
                                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                                    ItemRow(item: item)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            } 
    }
}
```

The code work well when I do not use a ScrollView to wrap the itemList.

[image]

However, when I put it inside a ScrollView. The content disappeared.

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true, content: {
                    itemList.overlay(SectionIndexTitles(proxy: proxy, titles: alphabet))
                })
            }
```

The content gone.

[image]

Any idea? I have also tried to enclose that in a VStack inside the ScrollView, also failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GeometryReader

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true, content: {
            itemList.overlay(SectionIndexTitles(proxy: proxy, titles: alphabet))
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new to swiftui, may I know the reason for this?

Comment: It might be creating a size problem. since we have two, scroll inside scroll so might be possible some problems with content size.

Comment: thanks, so it seems to be wrong to include a scrollview here.... hmmm

Comment: You can use the section footer as well.

Comment: Actually I tried to include a ScrollView that I would like to restrict overlay the Right Index to be within the List frame. It works if I include a scrollview, but the result also looks strange. Anyway, thanks a lot.